# Decimal separator lost after export from VB.Net to Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, export, decimal, transfer

I have numbers and text stored in a 1-dimensional string array which i need to send to excel.
For this operation i used a simple code:

```
    WPFtoExcel.Range("A1").Activate() 
    For item = 0 To 10 
    WPFtoExcel.ActiveCell.Value = Array(item)
    WPFtoExcel.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate()
    Next
```

Some numbers that have >2 decimals in the array loose their decimal points during the transfer:

- 5,65 appears in excel as 5,65 {OK}
- 0,0152 appears in excel as 0,0152 {OK}

but:

- 800,111 appears in excel as 800 111
- 800,1114 appears in excel as 8 001 114

I would appreciate if someone could suggest how such numbers can be transfered as is.

Regards,

Comment: Before the **Value** statement include **WPFtoExcel.ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "@"**

Comment: You are quite welcome!

Comment: @Gary'sStudent It would be helpful for future readers if you could post your comment as an answer so the OP can accept it (maybe with a short explaination why it works).

Comment: @Jens I have answered the post as per your request.

Comment: OP, please mark answer by @Gary'sStudent as answer on your question if that helped you solving your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you format the cell as *Text* before placing a value in it, Excel will refrain from changing it.  Include:

```
WPFtoExcel.ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "@"
```

before:

```
WPFtoExcel.ActiveCell.Value = Array(item)
```